# What is the best TeX renderer for Java applications?

Tags: math-mode, rendering, java

I want to be able to render mathematical equations in my Java applications. I have been using a library for Java called [JEuclid](http://jeuclid.sourceforge.net/) to achieve this. I have done some research on other libraries which could be used to achieve the same thing and I have come across libraries such as [SnuggleTeX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snuggletex/) and [JMathTeX](http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/).

My question is are there any other Java libraries which would be better suited for displaying mathematical equations or are more up to date and are better suited to work with newer versions of Java, such as Java SE 8. (The three libraries mentioned above were last updated years ago and aimed to be used with Java SE 5/6)

Comment: Would this question be better suited on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: The same as for [so] applies here and, moreover, the libraries you mention have nothing to do with TeX, apart perhaps sharing the syntax.

Comment: @egreg Would LaTeX be more suited?